# During hi-load moxi can return not found on existing keys

Tags: php, membase, libmemcache

In our project we are using CentOS5.6+php5.2.17+libmemcached+php memcached2+moxi+membase

First time i thought that it was app error, but after few weeks getting statistics and checks some situation i found that during hi load on moxi, it can return key not found on keys that exist in membase.

Does anyone else had this issue? May be there is some patch

Comment: Ijust get result from my logging system on production server. Problem realy exist. Under heavy load when Moxi pool is beasy it can response with NOTFOUND or libmemcached think that it is NOTFOUND response.

Comment: So if you use this libmemcached and moxi be carefull and always make check of result few times.

Comment: I will try to test library in the next few days to know what cause this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no situation where you're receiving a not found.  There can be situations, especially under high load (particularly during inserting) that you can get errors back.  Depending on the client, you may not be able to distinguish between an error and a not found.

Also, you don't mention which release you're using.  If you're on Membase 1.7.1 or later, that would be best.  There are important issues in each of the previous releases with moxi.

Comment: we use Moxi and Membase 1.7.1.1. Under php there is only one good memcached library it's libmemcached/php-pecl-memcached. Also membase developers as an example use this library. So even if problem in client library it still big problem. I will try to test library in the next few days to know what cause this bug.

Comment: i remove moxi proxy but the problem remains. So it can be Couchbase or it can be Memchached library, i think second more probable. So i trying now to switch to Couchbase client library to look for the changes

Comment: I'd originally posted that in October 2011.  Since then Couchbase Server 1.8 and then 2.0 have been released.  The not found is likely a known issue with moxi 1.7, and I know for certain it's fixed in 1.8 so moving to 1.8 or 2.0 would be advisable.